# Changing table's cell background color using PHP while loop

Tags: php, css, loops, while-loop, html-table

I need to change the background color of cells with freezing temperature (32F, 0C) to #bff9ff but have some difficulties. I tried to print CSS class inside `<td>` but seems it just doesn't work properly inside the loop and being printed at the same time.

However, it's half a problem. How can I identify those cells with freezing temp and below not manually but using PHP?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Unit 3 part 2</title>

        <style>
            table {
                font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
            }

            tr:hover {
                background-color:#bff9ff;
                }

            td, th {
                border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 8px;``
            }
            .cell {
                background-color: #00bfff;
                }    

        </style>

</head>
<body>

    <table border="1" cellpadding="3">

        <thead>
            <th>Fahrenheit</th>
            <th>Celsius</th>
        </thead>

        <?php
        $fahrenheit = 50;

        while ($fahrenheit >= -50) {

            $celsius = ($fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;

            print "<tr><td>$fahrenheit</td><td>$celsius</td></tr>";

            $fahrenheit -= 5;
            $celsius -= 5;



        } ?>

    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding an if statement to test the temperature, and then adding a class to the td tags, that should take care of it.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Unit 3 part 2</title>
    <style>
        table {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }
        tr:hover {
            background-color:#bff9ff;
            }
        td, th {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;``
        }
        .cell {
            background-color: #00bfff;
            }
        .cell.freezing {
            background-color: #bff9ff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="3">
        <thead>
            <th>Fahrenheit</th>
            <th>Celsius</th>
        </thead>
        <?php
        $fahrenheit = 50;
        while ($fahrenheit >= -50) {
            $celsius = ($fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
            $class = '';
            if($fahrenheit <= 32) {
                $class = ' freezing';
            }
            print "<tr><td class='cell $class'>$fahrenheit</td><td class='cell $class'>$celsius</td></tr>";
            $fahrenheit -= 5;
            $celsius -= 5;
        } ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you, please accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a CSS class called "freezing".  Use an if add the freezing class, e.g.,

```
"<td class='$freezing'></td>"
```

Basically evaluate this:

```
if (32 <= $farenheit || 0 <= $celcius) { 
  $freezing = "freezing";
}
```

Edit: CSS

```
.freezing {
  background-color: #bff9ff;
}
```